# Reading XML short notation in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
<METADATA>
<FIELDS>
<FIELD attrname="BRAND" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="15"/>
</FIELDS>
<PARAMS/>
</METADATA>
<ROWDATA>
<ROW BRAND="180S" STYLE="LUSH-EAR-WARMER" BARCODE="10823452061" STORE_PRICE="0.00" OH="12"/>
-----<ROW WITH ATTRIBUTES REPEATS)
------
</ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

I am getting it via a web source through a php script

1. I want to read each

   I want to extract value of BARCODE

   I want to extract value of OH

what I have tried is

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("final.xml");

    foreach ($xml->DATAPACKET->ROWDATA->ROW as $c) {

        $attrib = $c->attributes();
        echo("<br /><br />");
        echo("Barcode" . $attrib[BARCODE] . "<br />");
        echo("OH:" . $attrib[OH] . "<br />");
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

and I get error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...

can somebody help me troubleshoot this and help me solve my issue?
thanks a million

Comment: It's not the cause of your problem, but `$attrib[BARCODE]` should be `$attrib['BARCODE']` - the `BARCODE` is a string, not a magic word. PHP guesses what you mean, but you really shouldn't be writing code that relies on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there.

`$xml` represents `<DATAPACKET>`, so don't repeat it, but:

```
foreach ($xml->ROWDATA->ROW as $row) {
    echo "$row[BARCODE] <br />";
}
```

see it in action: http://3v4l.org/4gWAl